# Live USB KDE Manjaro stuck at 'reached target graphical interface' 3060 ti

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, live-usb, graphics, display-manager

Then i can alt-f2 and log in without graphical interface and mhwd -l gives bunch of "...MHWDCONFIG is invalid"

Is 3060 ti too new right now?
What to do?

[image: mhwd -li]

[image: startx]

tried nouveau.nomode=0 but same results theres a chance though it didn't apply properly cause i never done it before

Guys i am two clicks from windows 10 i am that desperate. I tried Ubuntu and manually installed .run drivers from NVIDIA site but Ubuntu blender from repo didnt cooperate with them apparently. Perhaps i will install win10 now and return to Manjaro at a later date. Linux is so snappy tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using manjaro-architect, choosing 5.9 kernel, then later chroot into installation, [switch to testing branch](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Switching_Branches)

```
sudo pacman-mirrors --api --set-branch testing
sudo pacman-mirrors --fasttrack 5 && sudo pacman -Syy
```

installing nvidia-460 packages from testing branch

```
sudo pacman -S linux59-nvidia-460.32.03-1
```

then installing `video-nvidia` driver using `mhwd` (which installs the correct version `460.32.03`)

```
sudo mhwd -i pci video-nvidia
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found that kernel 5.10 is even better because it didn't reach EOL.